# How to make a property in react class state with union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is my state

```
constructor(props: ListProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: this.props.alreadySelected
        ? this.props.alreadySelected
        : {
            name: "Select Item"
          },
      isOpen: false,
      page: 0,
      itemsList: [],
      ready: false,
      loadMore: false,
      filter: "" // filter string
    };
  }
```

I need to have the itemsList array to suppor two types: "ProjectDtoImpl and IssueDtoImpl"

Comment: As this is a list, it feels like generics would be a better solution than a discriminated union.  This is because it's likely you will have the requirement to create a list for yet another type in future.

Comment: @Oliver may be u can give me good link, to find an example, because i also think that my solution is non-expandable

Comment: I'd code for the requirements in front of you. Union type should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet - All for sticking to requirements, however there's hardly any difference in effort between the two.  What is a better tool for the problem?  In *my opinion* it would be generics.

Comment: In my opinion, a union describes the required type much better than a generic in this case. The component expects an array of one or other of the mentioned types.

Answer (score 1):

you can put type as

```js
itemsList: Array<ProjectDtoImpl | IssueDtoImpl>
```

or

```js
itemsList: ProjectDtoImpl[] | IssueDtoImpl[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props: ListProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // ...
      itemsList: [] as (ProjectDtoImpl | IssueDtoImpl)[],
    };
  }
```